# creating search engine friendly urls with PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not very familiar with reg exp, mod_rewrite and modifying of .htaccess. I want to create Search engine optimized links such that a visitor does not have to

1. see the file type i.e company.php becomes company
2. See the complete query string

What I currently have is :
http://www.mysite.com/company.php?company_id=74&name=DesignSourceLtd

What I want to look like is
http://www.mysite.com/company/74/DesignSourceLtd

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a big job with PHP, just be sure that you'll be creating clean urls, so remove special-chars and german umlauts (if any).

Just turn your link from  http://www.mysite.com/company.php?company_id=74&name=DesignSourceLtd to http://www.mysite.com/company/74/DesignSourceLtd in your php scripts.

Now, in your .htaccess file, do something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&name=$3
```

This will lead you to: 
    index.php?page=company&id=74&name=DesignSourceLtd

Comment: Thanx. With your code, If I placed http://www.mysite.com/company/74/DesignSourceLtd on my browser would it automaticcaly go to the correct page

Comment: Yeah, it should be. This uses a global index.php page for further redirecting. But you can also change it to `RewriteRule ^([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ $1.php?id=$2&name=$3`

to open the page given as first paramter, i.e. company.php?id=...&name=...